# How To make these effect like on MesutOezil webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

how can I make effects like they are on [Mesut Oezils webpage](http://www.mesutoezil.com/de)
I mean the effect where the background moves slower as the rest of the page. Or the effect at the end of the page where the last content scrolls up and the footer stands. Is there a jquery plugin or how do I make this?

And a last question: For example I have a big Image with opacity 1 on my landing page. How can I turn the opacity down to 0.3 when I start to scroll down (and the image stays with position:fixed). It would be cool when the opacity is based on the scrolled px until a minimum like 0.3 so that it is not an animation that is triggered at a fixed point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first effect is called Parallax Scrolling. Here you have a jquery plugin, for example: http://stephband.info/jparallax/

For the Fade On Scroll effect, you can also use jquery. Here you got an example: http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/1/

The html code for this Fade On Scroll:

```
<html>
    <body style="height:9999px;">
        <div id="fading" style="margin-top:200px;background:#aaa;">Fading</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The javascript code for this Fade On Scroll:

```
var fadeStart=100 // 100px scroll or less will equiv to 1 opacity
    ,fadeUntil=200 // 200px scroll or more will equiv to 0 opacity
    ,fading = $('#fading')
;

$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop()
        ,opacity=0
    ;
    if( offset<=fadeStart ){
        opacity=1;
    }else if( offset<=fadeUntil ){
        opacity=1-offset/fadeUntil;
    }
    fading.css('opacity',opacity).html(opacity);
});
```

**Updated JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/CqrJV/

Comment: good answer. Thanks. But how can I let stop the fadeout at opacity 0.3?. And how do I get the effect that mesut oezil has on the footer?

Comment: You just have to change `opacity=0` to `opacity=0.3`. The effect on the footer is the same Parallax Scrolling; it just has more than one layers. By the way, as you consider the answer good, please acccept it.

Comment: have a problem: I updated the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z7E9u/968/ and the opacity goes down to 0 and then up to 0.3.